# Настроить редирект на Nginx, который будет убирать знак вопроса в конце url, если после него ничего не идет

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Настроить редирект на Nginx, который будет убирать знак вопроса в конце url, если после него ничего не идет. Например

https://itc-life.ru/nastrojka-pochtovogo-servera-exim4
/? -> https://itc-life.ru/nastrojka-pochtovogo-servera-exim4/

Comment: А я бы задавал вопрос, как избавиться от создания таких ссылок. Я вот недавно написал правило редирект в апаче, которое создаёт такие ссылки с пустыми вопросами, но вот разбираться стал бы именно на апаче, а не думать над костылем для nginx. Может и вам стоит лечить корень проблемы, а не последствия? Это откуда такие ссылки берутся?

Comment: с помощью rewrite делается на раз. с какой проблемой вы столкнулись при решении задачи?

Comment: Для сео прпродвижения необходима такая шляпа..

Comment: Apache2 не использую принципиально...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сработал такой вариант

```
if ($request_uri ~* "\?$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1/ permanent;
}
```