# Настроить редирект nginx с https://itc-life.ru/nginx/? на https://itc-life.ru/nginx/

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Настроить редирект nginx с https://itc-life.ru/nginx/? на https://itc-life.ru/nginx/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настроить редирект на Nginx, который будет убирать знак вопроса в конце url, если после него ничего не идет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742301/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-nginx-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-url-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb)

Answer (score 0):

Сработал такой вариант

```
if ($request_uri ~* "\?$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1/ permanent;
}
```